# "Юмористические" причины голоса против. Минусы под настроение\Просто так

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, голоса-против

Когда мне поставили минус за [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/625025/220571), я попросил прокомментировать его. Получил следующий [комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624991/vw-%d0%b8-vh-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-media/625025#comment874029_625025):

> хотел поставить плюс, но передумал, когда понял, что ответ сводится к призыву в Игил, запрещенной в РФ организации. Так что я поставил минус.

Разумеется в ответе ничего такого не было. Допустимы ли голоса против с произвольными формулировками и надуманными причинами. Допустим (просто пофантазирую для того, чтобы просто понять правила и допустимость):

- У меня просто плохое настроение
- Сегодня фаза новолуния\полнолуния, планеты в каком-либо положении и т.д.
- Ответ [оскорбляет чувства верующиx](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2).

В общем такой вопрос: допустима ли любая "юмористическая" причина голоса против либо это считается нарушением?

Comment: Насколько я помню, минус там уже был. Вполне возможно, что оба. Точно ли с этим комментарием добавился минус?

Comment: @Qwertiy Оба минуса были до него.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Система голосования за ответы необходима, чтобы отделить плохие ответы от хороших так, чтобы достойные внимания были всегда наверху (мы полагаем, что лучше всех эту задачу могут решить заинтересованные участники сообщества). Таким образом, голосовать следует строго исходя из своего профессионального опыта и содержимого ответа на момент голосования (если ответ улучшен в будущем, следует проголосовать снова, при необходимости).

С другой стороны, голос – субъективен. У каждого из нас разный профессиональный и жизненный опыт. Принуждать никто ни к чему никого не будет, но если система (сообщество или модераторы) определит, что голос был отдан с намерениями навредить системе, голос будет аннулирован.

---

Конкретно в данном случае, как мне кажется, имеет место быть неуместная шутка, не более. Подобные комментарии, как верно заметил @PavelMayorov, следует удалять, отметив тревогой.

Comment: _"имеет место быть неуместная шутка"_ - скорее невнимательность, кому отвечаешь на комментарий. Возможно, что-то ещё. Кстати, а действительно ли был минус, или был только комментарий?

Comment: @Qwertiy _действительно ли был минус, или был только комментарий?_ – это история умалчивает.

Answer (score 15):

Голосовать против можно свободно, вовсе не указывая никакую причину. Тех, кто голосует осознанно, все равно будет больше.

Если пользователь привел откровенно дурацкую причину своего "минуса" в комментарии  - на такой комментарий можно кинуть тревогу "неконструктивный" (только не надо думать об этом как о мести - неконструктивные комментарии удаляются чтобы не засорять сайт).

Answer (score 8):

*«Юмористическая»* причина голоса против - это конечно не особо приятно. Как уже сказал @PavelMayorov - голосовать можно свободно, вовсе не указывая никакую причину. И это действительно так, ведь в правилах не указано такого пункта.

НО! Я против того, чтобы минусы у ответов не комментировались. Раз уж Вы прочли данный ответ и сочли его неудовлетворительным, то напишите пару слов о своем решении, так, отвечающий будет знать, что допустил ошибку или написал *чушь*. Но опять же - есть и обратная сторона медали. Ты знаешь о том, что написав комментарий к своему минусу - начнется глубокое выяснение причины того, почему же все таки **минус**. А это что? Правильно: время, нервы и прочее. Не всегда находятся участники, с которыми можешь что-то спокойно обсудить.

Думаю, что именно по причине нашей неуравновешенности и упрямости полученные минусы зачастую не комментируют, так как не хотят *глубоких* обсуждений и траты времени.

Немного отступил от темы, вернемся. Минусы под настроение или просто так - это результат того, что участник сообщества не понимает, что так делать не стоит. Ведь если ответ не плохой, тем более если он решает поставленный вопрос, то зачем туда минус ставить? Непорядок. Думаю, на этот счет система бессильна и нельзя отследить такой *«минус по настроению»*, наверняка и модераторы не в силах сделать этого.

«юмористическая» причина голоса против конечно не допустима, но увы счесть это нарушением нельзя. Точнее говоря, комментарий конечно же можно счесть нарушением профессиональной беседы, но вот голос против - нет. Кто знает, может быть комментарий был шуточным, а причина минуса - нет. Юмор - это конечно весело, но уж лучше, если будет названа реальная причина минуса, либо лучше промолчать, если нет желания обсуждать. Либо вообще - воздержаться от голосования, ведь практически всегда найдется тот, кто скажет тебе о том, в чем ты не прав. Ну, по крайней мере я стараюсь надеяться на то, что такой человек появится :)

Answer (score 5):

Этот комментарий был оставлен после [другого](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624991/vw-%d0%b8-vh-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-media/625025#comment873161_625011), который был моим:

> Хотел поставить плюс, но передумал, когда понял, что ответ сводится к "всегда и везде используйте пиксели". Принципиально не согласен.

Думаю, аналогия явно прослеживается:

> хотел поставить плюс, но передумал, когда понял, что ответ сводится к призыву в Игил, запрещенной в РФ организации. Так что я поставил минус.

Правда я минус не ставил - я вообще никак не голосовал за тот ответ. Идея была в том, что начало мне понравилось, но по мере чтения я передумал и не стал ставить ничего.

А вот по какой причине ответный комментарий (возможно, ещё и с минусом) оказался поставлен к совершенно чужому вопросу - мне не понятно. Возможно, следовало на него ответить какой-то фразой, призывающей обратить внимание, что ты никак не связан с этой историей.

PS: Интересно, что даже в этой теме, разбирая конкретную ситуацию, никто не обратил внимания на этот факт...